# Ruby code that selects particular members of the hash

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby and still learning. I'm working on extending an app that was in production a few months ago. Right now, I need to read a piece of code and extract the logic to a flowchart. In the app, I came across this line of code:

```
return_var = condition ? 
             @memberObject.select{|var| !var.has_key?(:key_of_interest) or var[:key_of_interest]} : 
             @memberObject
```

I've done a copy paste and replaced only the variable names. The code is exactly as it is above. 
I feel that this code should reduce down to simply:

```
return_var = @memberObject
```

Is there something subtle here that I'm missing? I'm hesitant to make the change since this app was supposedly in production and dealing with real data. Shouldn't Key_of_interest have no bearing on the select statement since it is negating it and ORing it with itself?

NOTE : This is my first time asking on stackoverflow. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong while asking this question. Also, I created a test ruby file and made dummy hashes with keys and tried it out. I got the result I expected but I feel there is more to this.

Comment: `var[:key_of_interest]` can return nil or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `var` was a hash, [method `has_key`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F) will check whether it an item with key `:key_of_interest`.

```
var.has_key?(:key_of_interest)  # true or false
```

On the contrary, below code will fetch the value associated with the key `:key_of_interest`

```
var[:key_of_interest]  # Could be `nil`
```

In Ruby, `false` and `nil` are considered *falsy* values, and everything else is considered *truthy* - which means

```
if falsy then
  # this block will never execute
end
```

So, what does below expression evalutes to?

```
!var.has_key?(:key_of_interest) or var[:key_of_interest]
```

It will be true if hash `var` does not have key `:key_of_interest`, or if it has a key `:key_of_interest`, then, its value is not `nil`.

Based on code snippet below, one would come to conclude that `@memberObject` is an array of hash.  So below code will filter out such hashes from `@memberObject` which have `nil` set for key `:key_of_interest` if certain `condition` was met

```
return_var = condition ? 
             @memberObject.select{|var| !var.has_key?(:key_of_interest) or var[:key_of_interest]} : 
             @memberObject
```

Comment: Accepting answer because of the detailed clear explanation. Thanks!

Comment: I did upvote them, I just dont have enough reputation points(15). My upvotes are hidden.

Comment: @OmeySalvi Sorry, realized it later - have removed my comment !

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

```
@memberObject.select { |var| !var.has_key?(:key_of_interest) or var[:key_of_interest] }
```

will return only the hashes inside `@memberObject` that don't have a given key or the key has *truthy* value. It will exclude ones, where the given key is present in the key, but its value is `nil` or `false`.

In other words:

```
@memberObject = [{:key_of_interest=>nil}]
@memberObject.select { |var| !var.has_key?(:key_of_interest) or var[:key_of_interest] }
  # => []
```